# "file" command in linux differing in output across machines

Tags: linux, file-type, libmagic

I ran the "file" command on two identical machines running the same OS and on the same file, but on one machine it identified the file type as "rtf" and on the other as just "data". Can anyone help me figure out why this might be happening?

Comment: Verify the files are actually the same first. Try `sha1sum` to get the hash. Is it the same on both systems?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried md5sum. They are identical.

Comment: Check `file --version` on both systems. That will also tell you the files referenced for magic values.

Comment: Done. All identical md5sum values

Comment: Probably different *MAGIC* files in both machines?  http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Comment: No, even they are the same. Checked the MD5SUM

Comment: Found the bug. It was a different magic.mgc file on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The magic.mgc file was different.